# Handling EXCEPTION response from WMS Server

Tags: openlayers-3

I tried to get a map image from a wms server using the following code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Playing with fis broker berlin</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../libs/ol3/css/ol.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/samples.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script src="../../libs/ol3/js/ol.js"></script>

<script>

  var imageSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wms/senstadt/k_dtk50',
    params: {
      'LAYERS': '0',
      'REQUEST': 'GetMap',
      'STYLES': ['default'],
      'SRS': 'EPSG:4326',
      'BBOX': [13.079, 52.3284, 13.7701, 52.6877],
      'WIDTH': '256',
      'HEIGT': '256',
      'FORMAT': 'jpeg'
    }
  })

  imageSource.on('imageloaderror', function (event) {
    var imageState = event.target.getState()
    var request = event.image.n

    console.log('imageloaderror, state = ' + imageState)
    console.log('request: ' + request)
  })

  var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    opacity: 0,
    source: imageSource
  })

  var view = new ol.View({
    center: [13.4297269, 52.4594867],
    zoom: 10
  })

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [imageLayer],
    view: view
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

ol3 fails to show the image, because the wms sends backs a xml exception report instead of jpeg data meaning 
*crs is not permitted: EPSG:3857*. 
On the java console we see the message 
*Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml ...*

I understand, that the image source is not set up correctly. This needs further investigaton by me. **But My question is:** 
How can I catch the message  *crs is not permitted: EPSG:3857* and any other error messages from the wms server by the ol script?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use XHR to load the image and get the exception text, see this thread for some inspiration:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ol3-dev/39tX1fSeSc0/KGURE6NrexIJ

```
    imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
      progress('start');
      var img = image.getImage();
      if (typeof window.btoa == 'function') {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', src, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
          if (this.status == 200) {
            var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
            var i = uInt8Array.length;
            var binaryString = new Array(i);
            while (i--) {
              binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
            }
            var data = binaryString.join('');
            var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type');
            if (type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
              img.src = 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + window.btoa(data);
            } else {
              error($.parseJSON(data));
            }
          } else {
            error(this.statusText);
          }
          progress('end');
        };
        xhr.send();
      } else {
        img.onload = function() {
          progress('end');
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
          progress('end');
          error();
        };
        img.src = src;
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks bartvde, but I don't want to do the xhr by myself, because this should be done  by ol, and it is done. But in the case of an error from the wms server I want to bring this up. Although I found the hook via *imageloaderror* to become aware of an error, I miss the access to the message *Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml ...*.

Comment: OpenLayers does not request the image by XHR. The only way to get the error text is to do the request by XHR. Or you should switch to EXCEPTIONS INIMAGE if your WMS supports this.